# Global marker for UI test automation in aura

Tags: aura, locker-service

What is a good way to set a "marker" for a UI test automation? Right now my application has quite a bit of background server calls that I want to wait to complete.

I am considering adding some sort of property to a window or document that Selenium can poll.

So far these do work within application, but are undefined for outside of locker container or however:

- window.foo = true
- document.foo = true
- sessionStorage.setItem('foo', true)
- localStorage.setItem('foo', true)

document.cookie worked, but adds some noise to the key: `LSKey[MyNs]foo=true`;

**EDIT**: Managed to make it work using cookies. It's pig ugly, but it works. However, doesn't work other way around - I only wanna set this cookie when app detects it's running in CI. document.cookie while in aura returns "", even when CI sets one up.

Comment: What automation tool(s) are you using?

Comment: Selenium / webdriver